# Export from DWG to Excel

Tags: autocad

Good day

I have map same which like on Picture. 
Link for real map http://www.mediafire.com/file/y3foq3yydhdppfb/MABELAH-S1_1.dwg#!

And from this map I need get only ping numbers (1 layer: N-PLOTNUM) to 1 column in excel sheet

I have only Autodesk AutoCAD map 3D 2012

I tried google research form manual but I do not find result..

Can you please send me link with manual or write down points for export.

Thank you.

[image: map]

Comment: which approach are you looking for? and language? LISP, .NET, VBA? Desktop or Cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Explore AutoCAD's built-in DataExtraction command.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ATTOUT (Express Tool)](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-899B195A-EFF0-4AEC-B0F8-7444EC75D649-htm.html)

This allows to to export attribute data to a file, where it can even be edited and reimported back into the corresponding attributes.